# If two PostgreSQL table has gist index, can their union be considered as an indexed table?

Tags: postgresql, indexing, postgresql-9.3

I have three tables, `table_a`, `table_b`, `table_c`. All of them has gist index.
I would like to perform a left join between `table_c` and the UNION of `table_a` and `table_b`.
Can the UNION be considered "indexed"? I assume it would better to create new table as the UNION, but these tables are huge so I try to avoid this kind of redundancy.

In terms of SQL, my question:

Is this

```
SELECT * FROM myschema.table_c AS a
LEFT JOIN
(SELECT col_1,col_2,the_geom FROM myschema.table_a
UNION
SELECT col_1,col_2,the_geom FROM myschema.table_b) AS b
ON ST_Intersects(a.the_geom,b.the_geom);
```

equal to this?

```
CREATE TABLE myschema.table_d AS
SELECT col_1,col_2,the_geom FROM myschema.table_a
UNION
SELECT col_1,col_2,the_geom FROM myschema.table_b;

CREATE INDEX idx_table_d_the_geom
ON myschema.table_d USING gist
(the_geom)
TABLESPACE mydb;

SELECT * FROM myschema.table_c AS a
LEFT JOIN myschema.table_d AS b
ON ST_Intersects(a.the_geom,b.the_geom);
```

Comment: Unrelated to your problem, but: Postgres 9.3 is [no longer supported](https://www.postgresql.org/support/versioning/)  you should plan an upgrade as soon as possible.

Comment: Yes unfortunately I know this, but it is a work related and I am not a decision maker...

Comment: You may want to look at query plan. You will see there if postgres uses indexes or not.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can look at the execution plan with `EXPLAIN`, but I doubt that it will use the indexes.

Rather than performing a left join between one table and the union of three other tables, you should perform the union of the left joins between the one table and each of the three tables in turn. That will be a longer statement, but PostgreSQL will be sure to use the index if that can speed up the left joins.

Be sure to use `UNION ALL` rather than `UNION` unless you really have to remove duplicates.

Comment: Great idea, thank you!
It does NOT use the index in the first version, however creating two separate left join and unioning them uses the index. 
(Thank you for the advice about `UNION ALL`, but I especially wanted to remove duplicates!)